# How to move the Proceed to Checkout button

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout, local.xml

I trying to move the `app/design/frontend/default/default/template/checkout/onepage/link.phtml` template that has the Proceed to Checkout button into the `cart.phtml` template. Copy and paste gives errors :) predictably!

How can I do that using the local.xml?

The reason is, I want it in a certain location and not all the methods just that single button.

Thank you

UPDATE

Here's where I'm trying put the button in the cart.phtml

```
<div class="cart-collaterals">
        <div class="totals">
        <!--RIGHT HERE-->
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('totals'); ?>
            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('coupon') ?>
            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('giftcards') ?>            
            <?php if(!$this->hasError()): ?>
            <ul class="checkout-types">
            <?php foreach ($this->getMethods('methods') as $method): ?>
                <?php if ($methodHtml = $this->getMethodHtml($method)): ?>
                <li><?php echo $methodHtml; ?></li>
                <?php endif; ?>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
            </ul>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('checkout_cart_widget') ?>
        </div>
   </div>   
<div class="cart-additional">
   <?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('cart_additional')->toHTML(); ?>
   </div>
</div>
```

When I just move the code for the button i.e. link.phtml into cart.phtml template like below I get a Magento error page and report (below).

```
<div class="cart-collaterals">
        <div class="totals">
        <!--BUTTON HERE START-->
<?php if ($this->isPossibleOnepageCheckout()):?>
<div class="checkout-button-holder">
    <button type="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('I\'m Ready to Checkout') ?>" id="button-onepage-checkout" class="button button-onepage-checkout<?php if ($this->isDisabled()):?> no-checkout<?php endif; ?>"<?php if ($this->isDisabled()):?> disabled="disabled"<?php endif; ?> onclick="window.location='<?php echo $this->getCheckoutUrl() ?>';">
    <?php echo $this->__('I\'m Ready to Checkout') ?></button>
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('cart_button_seals')->toHTML(); ?>
</div>
<?php endif?>
        <!--BUTTON HERE END-->
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('totals'); ?>
            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('coupon') ?>
            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('giftcards') ?>            
            <?php if(!$this->hasError()): ?>
            <ul class="checkout-types">
            <?php foreach ($this->getMethods('methods') as $method): ?>
                <?php if ($methodHtml = $this->getMethodHtml($method)): ?>
                <li><?php echo $methodHtml; ?></li>
                <?php endif; ?>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
            </ul>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('checkout_cart_widget') ?>
        </div>
   </div>   
   <div class="cart-additional">
      <?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('cart_additional')->toHTML(); ?>
   </div>
```

Get error: `a:5:{i:0;s:78:"Invalid method Mage_Checkout_Block_Cart::isPossibleOnepageCheckout(Array`

Comment: Where do you want to move and why you want to move it cart.phtml. There is already a code which calls the link.phtml

Comment: See my update above. The reason I can't just move the code is because with it comes all other payment buttons like PayPal etc.

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: See the update again : )

Comment: Are you using any extension? Because there is no such code <?php if ($this->isPossibleOnepageCheckout()):?> in default cart.phtml

Comment: That's what's in my installation's base link.phtml file has. I see it was used in Magento 1.7 also.

Comment: Please see this file which is magento 1.7.0.2 default cart.phtml. Update it according to your requirement it should work: https://github.com/amacgregor/magento-1.7.0.2/blob/master/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/cart.phtml

Answer (score -1):

Try the below code in your checkout_cart_index.xml file:

```
<move element="checkout.cart.methods.bottom" destination="cart.summary" before="checkout.cart.summary.title"/>
```

Comment: <move element="checkout.cart.methods.bottom" destination="cart.summary" before="checkout.cart.summary.title"/>