# How to move Proceed to checkout button On shopping cart page Magento 2

Tags: magento2, cart

You can try below code in checkout_cart_index.xml

```
<move element="checkout.cart.methods.bottom" destination="cart.summary" before="checkout.cart.summary.title"/>
```

Comment: Welcome, you seem to have accidentally posted a duplicate of your answer to the following https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/232190/how-to-move-the-proceed-to-checkout-button/256723#256723 as a new question, so this doesn't really seem to be a new question. If you really wanted to share the information as a new post on Stack Exchange you really should form this into a question and then post an answer separately, although you might want to explain it all a bit more clearly.

Answer (score 1):

Its working for me in checkout_cart_index.xml

```
<move element="checkout.cart.methods.bottom" destination="cart.summary" after="checkout.cart.totals"/>
```